# Lightweight migration / addPersistentStoreWithType hangs app launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

A few dozen iOS 6 users are seeing a problem where addPersistentStoreWithType seems to hang the app but doesn't seem to impact hundreds of thousands of other active users. Googling and searching the dev forums haven't helped yet. I am calling this and the app is just hanging for some users.

```
options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES, NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen};
[self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&addPersistentStoreError];
```

I don't see anything in the documentation that would indicate that this could throw an exception or why it would deadlock/hang for any reason. This repeatedly happened on each launch for these users, preventing the user from ever launching the app (short of reinstalling). The crashlogs we got all had exception code 0x000000008badf00d (anything that causes things to take too long on the main thread).

What could cause addPersistenStoreWithType to hang like this?

Comment: This happens when a migration takes longer than the watchdog allows your application to start up. The solution is to add the persistent store asynchronously and display something for the user while the migration takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue . Users have very huge data . My app is freezing at `addPersistentStoreWithType` method. Specifically I am facing this issue in iPad2. Where as in iPad3 data migration is working perfectly. We added the persistent store in high priority thread and display something for the user while the migration takes place.

```
(void)performLightweightMigrationInBackgroundWithStoreURL:(NSURL *)storeURL
 {
    [self.initializerDelegate willStartMigration];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
        NSDictionary *storeOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:&error]) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
               // we showed an alert message for migration failure
            });
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                // we showed an alert message for successful migration
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with potentially large DBs to migrate, I'd suggest you make sure you avoid initializing the persistent store (and running the migration) in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, since you only have a few seconds to get the app set up in that method before iOS kills it.  There's not a lot of headroom there.

Instead, launch the app, show a spinner or some other indication that you're loading content on your initial view controller, and then load the store after you return from `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` with `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and a delay of 0 or similar.